# Should [meta:answering-questions] be a synonym of [meta:answers]?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

From the meta-tag-wiki for answers:

```
For questions about answers: how to answer, whether specific answers are
appropriate, and so forth.
```

Most of the questions flagged with [answering-questions](/questions/tagged/answering-questions) fall under this definition.

And three other suggestions:

[useless-answers](/questions/tagged/useless-answers) -> [non-answers](/questions/tagged/non-answers)

[not-an-answer](/questions/tagged/not-an-answer)   -> [non-answers](/questions/tagged/non-answers)

Comment: unanswered is not the same as no-answers. see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/