# Proposed tag synonym suggestion privilege  - Sudo

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

Would "the powers that be" be willing to consider granting specific privileges to lower rep users?  Much like the appointed moderators, but with a very confined skill set?

Could certain lower-rep people be granted permissions to directly suggest tag synonyms instead of [posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96985) [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97563)?

This is not a request to lower the reputation level for this privilege, that and similar questions have been asked [several](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72157) [times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60415) [before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69263).

I can see the [perils](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62323) of letting a broader audience make synonym proposals.

It is not my desire to post 'white-noise' questions to Meta -- again just want to help in any way I can.

Comment: You can nudge one of those Meta mods on chat to do your bidding

Comment: If that is the preferred method, I would be happy to do so.

Comment: I think the tag synonym can be `peer-reviewed` before actual users vote on it.